# Showing all current visitors cursors live

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, cursor-position

What would be the best way of showing all the current visitors cursors live in each browser window?

Is this achievable at all, without too much lag?

This is my attempt with meteor js:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/rCSsroc4G4gYQGkAY/Leaderboard (mind the name, can't change it?)

http://allofthecursors.meteor.com/

cursors.js:

```
Cursors = new Mongo.Collection("Cursors");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
      if(!Session.get('cursorId')) {
        // todo: not unique enough!
        var cursorId = new Date();

        Session.set('cursorId', cursorId);
        Meteor.call('initCursor', cursorId);
      }
  });

  Template.cursor.helpers({
    cursor: function() {
      return Cursors.findOne({ cursorId: Session.get('cursorId') });
    },
    cursors: function() {
      return Cursors.find({ cursorId: { $ne: Session.get('cursorId') } });
    }
  });

  Template.cursor.events({
    "mousemove": function(event) {
      var x = event.pageX,
          y = event.pageY,
          cursorId = Session.get('cursorId');

      Meteor.call('updateCursor', cursorId, x, y);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.methods({
    'initCursor': function(cursorId) {
        Cursors.insert({
          cursorId: cursorId,
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        });
    },
    'updateCursor': function(cursorId, x, y) {
      Cursors.update(
        { cursorId: cursorId }, 
        { $set: { x: x, y: y }}
      );
    }
  });
}
```

cursors.html

```
<head>
  <title>cursors</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{> cursor}}

</body>

<template name="cursor">
    <div class="cursors-area">
        {{#each cursors}}
            <div class="cursor" style="top: {{y}}px; left: {{x}}px;"></div>
        {{/each}}

        <div class="my-cursor">
            {{cursor.cursorId}}: {{cursor.x}}, {{cursor.y}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

cursors.css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.cursors-area {
    height: 100vh;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    width: 11px;
    height: 17px;
    background-image: url(cursor.png);
}
```

**Thanks for the response evrybady. Here's an updated version.**

Added the streams package:
$ meteor add lepozepo:streams

The client side collection is only used to access the reactive capabilities.

cursors_2.js

```
Stream = new Meteor.Stream('public');

if( Meteor.isClient ) {

  Cursors = new Mongo.Collection(null);

  Template.cursor.events({
    'mousemove': function(event) {

      if (Meteor.status().connected) {
        Stream.emit('p', { 
          _id: Meteor.connection._lastSessionId,
          x: event.pageX, 
          y: event.pageY 
        });
      }

    }
  });

  Stream.on('p', function(p) {

    // how can I change this? 

    if( Cursors.findOne(p._id) === undefined ) {

      Cursors.insert({
        _id: p._id,
        x: p.x,
        y: p.y
      });

    } else {

      Cursors.update(p._id, {
          $set: {
            x: p.x,
            y: p.y
          }
        }
      );
    }

  });

  function getCursors() {
    return Cursors.find();
  }
  var throttledGetCursors = _.throttle(getCursors, 50);

  Template.cursor.helpers({
    cursors: throttledGetCursors
  });
}
```

Comment: I would recommend [using underscore to throttle the method calls](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle), so that it doesn't send a new method call every single time the mouse moves one pixel. To make the movement still appear somewhat smooth, you can put a css `transition` on the `top` and `left` properties, with the same duration as your throttle.

Comment: In addition to debouncing, you should probably use [streams](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/), which allows you to do realtime communication without MongoDB. That website is outdated though, to add the streams package to your app run `meteor add lepozepo:streams`

Comment: I tried using transitions but there was some strange lag going on. Not sure if I was able to set up the throttle correctly though.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two ways to go about this.

1. The first is to use the built-in APIs you have for client-server-client communication and record keeping, i.e. collections.  The advantage of this is that it's very straightforward and the reactivity and communication are taken care of for you.  If you go down this route, I think your current setup is overcomplicated - you're using methods to communicate changes in position from each client, and then using livedata to communicate it back again as the collection is synchronised.  Why not just write to the collection from the client?  I'd suggest something like this:

**CLIENT**

```
Template.body.events({
    'mousemove': function(event) {
        if (Meteor.status().connected) {
            Cursors.update(Meteor.connection._lastSessionId, {
                $set: {
                    x: event.pageX,
                    y: event.pageY
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**SERVER**

```
Meteor.onConnection(function(connection) {
    Cursors.insert({
        _id: connection.id,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    });
    connection.onClose(function() {
        Cursors.remove(connection.id);
    });
});
```

As well as obviating the need for session variables, that uses the session id to provide a unique cursor id for each client and removes it from the collection when they disconnect.  This is also preferable from a security perspective as it allows you to prevent users from updating cursors which don't share their connection id (via allow/deny) in case that would ever be a concern.

2. However, you still have the overhead of putting things into out out of the MongoDB, which will cause some latency.  As @sbking points out, the `lepozepo:streams` package ([docs here](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/)) allows you to communicate closer to the raw websocket and, whilst it will involve rather more plumbing, will result in less latency.  There was some discussion of this at the London DevShop in Dec 2015, the videos from which should be available soon.  It would be great if somebody could write a collection for pure server-client messaging (independent of collections), but I don't think that exists at present.

Also, agreed with @sbking that you should be debouncing updates with Underscore (*not* throttling).

Comment: To clarify for the OP, debouncing will only send updates n milliseconds after the user has stopped moving their cursor. Throttling will only send updates at most every n milliseconds, but will allow updates to be sent while the user is moving their cursor. The decision over which to use depends on how you want the application to work. Debouncing would result in fewer updates, though.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to exchange the collection with a stream. I'm not sure how to use react in this setup, according to the docs I can fake it with a client only collection, producing the proper dom-updates - but I'm getting some errors saying "insert" is not a function on my client "Cursors" collection.

Comment: "stream version" is up and running @ http://allofthecursors.meteor.com/ ... can definitely see a boost in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebRTC for this. Google for it.

Essentially you're going to use some JavaScript to connect your two browsers together, Meteor will send the handshake, then the two browsers can talk. From here, you can do all sorts of data intensive stuff without blowing up Meteor or your clients. Ez. Pz.